# Given a binary number, how do we get the last decimal digit?

Tags: binary

Given a binary representation of 25 i.e 11001, if I am interested only in the last decimal digit, how do I get it?

Comment: Just curious: Do you know a method and you're posting as if a puzzle for others? [Or did you just think up this question ?]

Comment: I was trying to solve a question in this link: http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/331/given-binary-stream-decimal-value-stream-becomes-divisible  . So, in this case, we just need to know if last digit is either 5 or 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From right to left, the binary place values (mod 10) are $1, 2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8, 6, \dots$.  You can add the  reduced (mod 10) place values with $1$s in them, and then mod your answer by ten.

In your example, $11001$, you would add $8 + 6 + 0 + 0 + 1=15\equiv 5 \pmod{10}$.

Comment: I was writing a similar answer.  It would be good to explicitly note that the binary place values (after the first) cycle with period $4$, so you can add $2$ times the $2^1s, 2^5s, 2^9s \dots $ places where there is a $1$ and so on for the others.  It may make the computation easier.  +1

Comment: if you get four 1's in a run (after the first), they can be ignored